# Whitelist IP in Apache2.4 based on Directory

Tags: apache, apache2

I have been trying to achieve a whitelist in apache where i want to allow all the request in /xyz uri to the public and but restric the access to all the other uri bases on the IP.This is the configuration that i have been trying but unfortunately it's not working Apache Version 2.4.41

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin 
        ServerName 


        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin 
        ServerName

        SSLEngine ON
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cert/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/key.pem

        DocumentRoot /var/www/abc


        <Directory /var/www/abc>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
        </Directory>
<Location /xyz>
Require all granted
</Location>
<Location />
Require ip ****
</Location>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/abc.de-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/abc-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried using the location option but once I put up a whitelist in / path it applies to all the directories and does not grant access to even the /xyz uri.

Also the /xyz uri loads many of the assets from the /abc/*** path as well

I have tried most of the solutions available on different sites but nothing seems to work